# Count and percentage values getting truncated in barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a barplot with count and percentage values. But for the highest value my proportion and percentage values are getting truncated. I have tried to increase the `margin`, but it increases the white space around the plot and does not result in showing the truncated values. What can be done to show all the values? I have tried ajusting with `hjust` but this creates issues for lesser values of the graph.

```
ggplot(occupation_summary, aes(x = n, y = reorder(par_occ, n), fill = par_occ)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(n, " (", scales::percent(proportion), ")", sep = "")),
        hjust = -0.05, size = 3) +
  labs(title = paste("Occupations of parents (Total:", p_num, ")"),
   x = "Number", y = "Occupation")  +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

In the resulting plot the top entry only shows the count 732 its percentage is not visible. How can I increase the plot area to show the percentage for this value?

[image]

Comment: You could expand the x scale at the upper end, i.e. try `+ scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(.05, .15))`. .05 = 5% = default expansion at the lower end, increase to 15 % at the upper end.

Comment: Though it gives a warning Warning: `expand_scale()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.3.0.
ℹ Please use `expansion()` instead.

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Switch to `expansion()`. Haven't used it for a while. (: